# Present URI in database as clickable link

Tags: sql, excel, powerbi, uri, powerquery

I have a table in a SQL Server 2019  that stores URI's like this:

```
documentID | documentlink
1 | \\server\share\documentid\Contract.pdf
2 | \\server\share\documentid\Salesnumbers.xlsx
3 | \\server\share\documentid\NicePicture.xlsx
```

These values are stored as nvarchar. Is there a way to make these clickable?
So that, when this table is for example read by PowerQuery users only have to click the link to open the file? It is assumed that only those filetypes are allowed for which the users have applications to view those files.

This does not necessarily have to be in SQL Server itself. If someone could tell me how to make it clickable in for example Excel or PowerBI, I would be gratefull also.

Comment: Database is for storing and processing the data. If you need to display this data and provide some user actions on it you need to use some external tool

Comment: That is why I used Powerquery as an example and mentioned excel and powerbi in the tags. I will make the question more clear.

Comment: The problem is that you require some action that actually doesn't do anything: you may copy link and paste it into the browser address bar. You may use any reporting tool, I'm sure every modern reporting tool may format URL as clickable (even Notepad++ can do this). There's nothing to suggest. What is the business scenario you need to reproduce?

Comment: Well, users need to open with a minimum effort the link in documentlink.
Copying and pasting works but I prefer clicking. But some how Excel won't make this inbto a clickable link, nor seems powerbi to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding file:\ in front of documentlink makes Excel makes it into a clickable link. My Google-fu abandoned me.